# What does . mean in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Consider this code example:

```
{
    $n1 = ucfirst(strtolower($n1));
    $n2 = ucfirst(strtolower($n2));
    $n3 = ucfirst(strtolower($n3));
    return $n1 . " " . $n2 . " " . $n3;
}
```

My book says the code will display:

William Henry Gates  (each name is the value of the variables)

So what do the `.` in between the quotes and the next variable do? I must have read over it, and I look back for it, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It concatenates (merges) strings

Comment: Ah I see. Simple enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Concatenation

Since you are trying to return the variable `$n1` with a space `$n2` with another space and `$n3`

You can also check [String Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) from PHP Manual for more information about this

One of the example to use the `.` operator or refer to String Operator from PHP manual

```
<?php
 $a = "Hello ";
 $b = $a . "World!"; // now $b contains "Hello World!"

 $a = "Hello ";
 $a .= "World!";     // now $a contains "Hello World!"
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The . operator concatenates strings.

The code converts `$n1`, `$n2`, and `$n3` into lowercase, then capitalizes the first letter, then combines all three names together with a space between each name.